# Server soap C#- client Java

Tags: c#, java, xml, soap

I've created a server that comunicate on a socket Tcp and a parser that analyzes the message between a server written in C# and a Client Java. All works but there is a waste of time when i've to add new xml message.

I discovered that Soap protocol is extensible and using it you save a lot of work in case of new message. What is the best Soap library already implemented in the two languages?

Is there a code generator as gsoap that autogenerate the code of the client (in Java) and the server (in C#) and the schema from the text of the messages as gsoap does for C and C++?

Comment: Useful search phrase, perhaps: "java WSDL generate" -- in theory at least -- the WSDL *defines* the SOAP contract just as [COM] IDL defines a COM contract.

Comment: (Less useful: If I had control over both the client and server I would consider [google protocolbuffer](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) or similar. This of course has the "downside" of not being a full-stack itself -- although those exist -- and not being SOAP which has ups and downs.)

Answer (score 1):

There IS a generator for C# that works much like gsoap: cssoap. It is not complete yet, but maybe it works for you. It can be found at http://audiocomplex.blogspot.com/p/cssoap-open-source-c-soap-webservice.html